# generating random enums

Tags: c++, enums

How do I randomly select a value for an enum type in C++?
I would like to do something like this.

```
enum my_type(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,h,J,V);
my_type test(rand() % 10);
```

But this is illegal...  there is not an implicit conversion from int to an enum type.

Comment: static_cast is a good friend in such situations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about:

```
enum my_type {
    a, b, c, d,
    last
};

void f() {
    my_type test = static_cast<my_type>(rand() % last);
}
```

Comment: +1 for less hard-coding, but I recommend the C++ style static_cast.

Comment: This won't work if the enum values aren't contiguous.

Comment: @einpoklum Can you give an example?

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart: `a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 16`. The `rand()` will give you invalid values.

Comment: ... also, never use `rand()`, it is [considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Use of C++ random number facilities now preferred

Answer (score 9):

There is no implicit conversion, but an explicit one will work:

```
my_type test = my_type(rand() % 10);
```

Comment: Some individual mentioned in the accepted answer that implicit conversion one won't work if the enum values aren't contiguous. Does it also apply to this?

Comment: @VolkanGüven Yes. This is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I solved a similar problem recently. I put this in an appropiate .cc file:

```
static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
```

Inside the header that defines the enum:

```
enum Direction
{
    N,
    E,
    S,
    W
};
static std::vector<Direction> ALL_DIRECTIONS({Direction::N, Direction::E, Direction::S, Direction::W});
```

And to generate a random direction:

```
Direction randDir() {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dis(0, ALL_DIRECTIONS.size() - 1);
    Direction randomDirection = ALL_DIRECTIONS[dis(gen)];
    return randomDirection;
}
```

Don't forget to

```
#include <random>
```