# C++ Randomly Assigning an enumerated type to a variable

Tags: c++, random, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generating random enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999012/generating-random-enums)

Lets say I have the following:

```
enum Color {        
    RED, GREEN, BLUE 
};
Color foo;
```

What I want to be able to do is randomly assign foo to a color. The naiive way would be:

```
int r = rand() % 3;
if (r == 0)
{
    foo = RED;
}
else if (r == 1)
{
    foo = GREEN;
}
else
{ 
    foo = BLUE;
}
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this. I have tried (and failed) the following:

```
foo = rand() % 3; //Compiler doesn't like this because foo should be a Color not an int
foo = Color[rand() % 3] //I thought this was worth a shot. Clearly didn't work.
```

Let me know if you guys know of any better way which does not involve 3 if statements. Thanks.

Comment: try foo = static_cast<Color>( rand() % 3 ); ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just cast an int to an enum, e.g.

```
Color foo = static_cast<Color>(rand() % 3);
```

As a matter of style, you might want to make the code a little more robust/readable, e.g.

```
enum Color {        
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    NUM_COLORS
};

Color foo = static_cast<Color>(rand() % NUM_COLORS);
```

That way the code still works if you add or remove colours to/from `Color` at some point in the future, and someone reading your code doesn't have to scratch their head and wonder where the literal constant `3` came from.

Comment: Thanks so much. And thank you for the style tip I actually never thought of that but its quite clever!

Comment: @PaulR, OP: Note that this works based on the (valid) assumption that the enum range is contiguous - which is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a cast:

```
foo = (Color) (rand() % 3);
```

Comment: It's tagged C++ though - use a C++ typecast, not a C typecast.

Comment: Bad habits never die... :) I'll let it that way though because otherwise it would be the exact same as your answer.

Comment: @Paul What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @user1413793: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast