# How to get random value from assigned enum in c++?

Tags: c++, random, enums

I want a random color from this enum:

```
enum Color {
red = 10,
black = 3,
pink = 6,
rainbow=99    
};

Color my_randowm_color = ...
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Why are your enum values so erratic? Any particular reason for this?

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999012/generating-random-enums

Comment: I can't choose the value of my colors, I want to use the enum to make it easy to compare color in my code etc

Comment: not duplicated because my enum has assign value

Comment: Given your use case, you might consider a different data type. Maybe a class is what you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to enumerate the values of an enum.

You can use a table:

```
std::vector<int> colors = {red, black, pink, rainbow};
```

and then pick a random element from it.

Picking a random element left as an exercise.

Comment: it's really ugly but it work... if the enum was bigger it will be a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a different approach based on my understanding of what the OP desires.

What you can do is generate a random number in a range of 0-3. As you have four colors. Then store your colors in an array. And use a function returning a random number as index of that array. In this manner You will get random colors among the ones you have.

eg.

```
random() {
// func definition
//  return random number in range of array indices
}

array = ["red","black","pink","rainbow"];

array[random()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a array containing possible enums and then generate random number for array index starting from 0 to total possible enum values.

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main() 
    {
       enum Color {   red = 10, black = 3, pink = 6, rainbow=99 };
       int max = 3;
       int min = 0;

       srand(static_cast <unsigned int> (time(0)));
       int randNum = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

       Color forRandomPurpose[] = { red, black, pink, rainbow };
       Color my_random_color = forRandomPurpose[randNum];

       std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
       std::cout << my_random_color << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Would you like to add some comments, what you have done above?

Comment: @JeJo added comments

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (-:

```
Color random_color() {
   int r = rand() % 4;
   return static_cast<Color>((r + 1) * 3 + (r >= 2) + (r >= 3) * 86);
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/j4YNMqWs41QJFeOB